# Proper way to write the cost function in SVM in Matlab - unable to understand 'Cost' matrix

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, svm

I want to apply SVM to an imbalanced dataset and [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736125/how-do-you-handle-data-imbalance-in-svm), [answer2](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/344774-using-fitcsvm-for-binary-linear-classification-of-unbalanced-data)  suggest that it is possible to do so by tuning the parameters of the `fitcsvm` function. ALthough, SVM may not be a good choice for imbalanced data, yet I want to see the result for educational purpose.

How do I tune the parameters in SVM to put greater penalty to misclassification error for the true class (labelled as `1`) since my data is naturally imbalanced, having less number of `1`'s in contrast to `0` (false). Only 2% are labelled as `1`.

- The data set has 1473 samples (98%) labeled as `0` and 27 samples (2%) as `1`.
- The training data has 1000   samples  labeled as `0` and 
  12  samples as `1`.
- The test data has 473 samples (97%) as `0` and 15 samples (3%) as `1`. I applied twice penalty to `1` by using a cost matrix, `c` as below:

> ```
> c=[0 2.2;1 0];
> model = fitcsvm(train_x,train_y,'KernelFunction', 'rbf', 'Cost',c);
> [predLabel,score] = predict(model,test_x);
> ```
>
> The result is

```
Precision for label 0: 9.692623e-01
Precision for label 1: NaN
Recall for label 0: 1
Recall for label 1: 0

Accuracy = 96.9%
Average err = 0.03
```

The confusion matrix is

```
    473     0
    15     0
```

The answer in the `predict` vector are all `1` labels. Obviously, the cost matrix is not working correctly. I cannot quite understand looking at the cost matrix if I am penalizing the misclassification of 0 (majority class) or 1(minority class). Why first row and first column element =0 and the other is 2. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be shown using some test data, for example the following:

```
rng(42)
X = randn(1000, 2);
y = rand(1000, 1) >= 0.98;
X(y==1, :) = X(y==1, :) + [2, 2];
```

A simple SVM with Gaussian kernel function will not work well due to the class imbalance:

```
model = fitcsvm(X, y, 'KernelFunction', 'rbf')
confusionmat(y, model.predict(X))

ans =

   979     2
    14     5
```

As you have already recognized, the `'Cost'` parameter can be used to compensate for the imbalance by placing a higher penalty on misclassifications of the minority class. In the two-dimensional case, the cost matrix is built up as follows:

```
[ Cost(0, 0),    Cost(0, 1)
  Cost(1, 0),    Cost(1, 1) ]
```

Now, `Cost(0, 0)` is the cost of classifying a sample belonging to class `0` as class `0`. This is a correct classification, so usually the cost is set to 0. Next, `Cost(0, 1)` is the cost of classifying a point belonging to class `0` as class `1`, i.e. a wrong classification.

In your example, class `0` is more likely to occur than class `1`, so we should impose a low penalty on classifying a sample from class `0` (the majority) as class `1` (the minority), and a high penalty on classifying a sample from class `1` (the minority) as class `0` (the majority). So `Cost(0, 1)` should be low and `Cost(1, 0)` should be high.

By setting `c = [0, 2.2; 1, 0]`, you did the opposite - you advised the `fitcsvm` function to rather classify a minority sample as majority than the opposite:

```
c = [0, 2.2; 1, 0];
model = fitcsvm(X, y, 'KernelFunction', 'rbf', 'Cost', c);
confusionmat(y, model.predict(X))

ans =

   981     0
    19     0
```

If you use the same weights in the cost matrix `c`, but switch `Cost(0, 1)` and `Cost(1, 0)`, then the desired effect will happen:

```
c = [0, 1; 2.2, 0];
model = fitcsvm(X, y, 'KernelFunction', 'rbf', 'Cost', c);
confusionmat(y, model.predict(X))

ans =

   973     8
     7    12
```

This does improve our result: over all we have a similar amount of misclassifications: 15 instead of 16 total misclassifications, but 12 out of our 19 samples of the minority class are correct with the new model, compared to only 5 before.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and such an easy to follow instructions. Could you please clarify the following points? (1) In my dataset actually only 2% is true positive class. By including the cost and without it, I am getting the same result in the confusion matrix and accuracy. I checked with different cost values such as 2.2, 3,4,5 but no effect. Therefore, is it possible that this approach is not suitable for my dataset? (2) Is there a range max and min for the cost value? How to decide whether to put 2 or 3 etc? and

Comment: (3) In general once the model is trained how do I use the trained model? I should use the trained model model on unseen data but what is the function for it in Matlab?

Comment: I saw no change in classification for cost value from 2.2 till 49, the cconfusion matrix remained the same which was `[473,     0;    15,     0]`. When I increased the cost from 2.2 to 50, only then did I see a change and got all correct predictions for the minority class `1` but then class `0` predictions became poor. Therefore, how do I know how much to increase the misclassification cost value?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your results, it seems that both classes belong to the same distribution. Try oversampling your training data (generating more positive samples using your available positive samples) and build your model on that, then test your model on the testing.